# Comparing a model before/after save with other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, callback

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.

I have a model (Task) which has attributes: :day, :room, :begin_time, :end_time, :gear, :notes, and others (which aren't relevant). I also have a linked_id_task attribute in a migration set on the Task model. And I have these relevant scopes (which I chain together):

```
scope :for_day, lambda { |day| where(day: day) }
scope :for_room, lambda { |room| where(room: room) }
scope :with_gear, lambda { |gear| where(gear: gear) }
@tasks_on_same_day = Task.for_day(self.day).for_room(self.room).with_gear(self.gear).all
@task_on_previous_day = Task.for_day(self.day.yesterday).for_room(self.room).with_gear(self.gear).last
@task_on_next_day = Task.for_day(self.day.tomorrow).for_room(self.room).with_gear(self.gear).first
```

Whether I'm creating a new task or updating a new one, I want to:

Check for previous and next tasks (**based on :begin_time**) in private instance methods prev? and next?. If there is a previous task, I want to update its :notes and add that task to the :linked_task_id; if there's a next task, I want to set self.notes with info about the next task and add it to :linked_task_id. If there aren't any tasks on the current day (above), previous day or next day, I'll return nil.

The previous and next day is simple, because I'll get the last task from the previous day (if it exists) or first task from the next day. If there are several tasks on the current day, I want be able to have the task sorted in to easily find the previous and next task, i.e.

```
@self_id = @tasks_on_same_day.index(self)
```

and use that index to update_attributes of the prev or next tasks. The problem is, I don't think that a newly created task or an updated task (i.e., I update the begin_time) will be available in a before_save callback.

I can create a class method to sort self into a list of the current day tasks.

I'm not looking for someone to code this for me, but I am confused about the approach I should take.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To preface my answer: I'm a newbie.

After being frustrated for awhile, I started watching RailsCasts, picking up where I left off from last night. And it dawned on me (watching a video about ActiveRecord querying) that I'm an idiot.

I haven't tried this yet, but I can just query for something like...

```
@previous = Task.for_day(self.day).for_room(self.room).with_gear(self.gear).where('begin_time < ?' self.begin_time).last
@next = Task.for_day(self.day).for_room(self.room).with_gear(self.gear).where('begin_time > ?' self.begin_time).first
```

That's amazingly easy. To make this question useful, what's the performance effect of a long query string like that?

Comment: Performance really isn't an issue with that in rails 3, all of those chained methods just get added in the WHERE clause. The query isn't actually even run until you do something with it(ie. @next.each do |next|) So you should be fine.

Comment: Good point, Magicmarkker. I recall Ryan Bates saying, because of rails 3 lazy loading (i.e. queries return ActiveRecord::Relation objects), nothing is actually queried until an action, like you mentioned. Like my calls to .last and .first.  Thank you.